# Why was my post was removed from the HNQ list?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hot-questions-list

**Question**:
Why was my recent post: [Side of the largest possible cube inside a cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504529/side-of-the-largest-possible-cube-inside-a-cone) was removed from the HNQ list?

**Context**:
I **do** realize related *general* discussions (see below) but I don't feel right the *specific question* was removed from the HNQ.

Related posts in meta:

1. [Why was a question proactively removed from Hot Network Questions even though it never appeared there in the first place?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34327) The question was removed as it was answered by the active mod itself. Not so in my case.
2. [Why did a moderator remove my question from HNQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30752) The question was deemed subpar as it was closed and re-opened. Not so in my case.
3. [Under what criteria should we remove questions from the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671) It's quite an open-ended discussion, but the mod answered one of the reasons as clickbait-y titles. Not so in my case. The title is apt.
4. [Mod removing questions out of HNQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35045) It's mentioned that if a users' questions frequently end up on the list then the mod considers the user gaming the system. Most likely in my case, this was my first question to make it to the HNQ list. But I'm definitely not trying to game the system.
5. $\LaTeX$ is not hard and fast rule either. [This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508469/why-cant-two-circles-intersect-at-more-than-2-points) didn't have it throughout the **two** days and it's title was apt.

Comment: "If they are not good, they'll automatically come down and replaced by a better one" What exactly does it mean?

Comment: If people don't like it, and some other question is popular/hot then it will be automatically replaced (I think).

Comment: I cannot find anything on meta justifying what you claim.

Comment: @ArcticChar In the discussion link that I mentioned, it was said so in the comments.

Comment: @ArcticChar [This comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list#comment132986_30673)

Comment: I still see no justification. The only thing I can find is that while a post gets into HNQ, it will be taken down [before 72 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt). It's not clear what else would make a post no longer eligible.

Comment: If this is intended to be about *this particular question* maybe the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be suitable here? (See [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for the guidance on how to use this tag.)

Comment: @ArcticChar the post I'm talking of was taken down after an hour only(!).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks I've added that though it's not perfectly suitable because of latter part of the question(?).

Comment: The reasons that questions are removed from the HNQ have been discussed before.  If someone posts a new question to meta every time they disagree with one of those choices, meta will become useless.  I don't think that there is anything new here, so I have closed this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @XanderHenderson generally the reasons were not a good heading or too easy but that does not seems the case here. So, since I'm primarily asking for reasons related to my question and not a general discussion, so I don't think it should have been closed. Please consider re-opening it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have provided the reasons for each link too now. Kindly re-consider re-opening.

Comment: All of these recent HNQ-complaining meta posts are based on "why was mine removed?", and is packed full of unsupported claims and paranoid accusations. If you want to open a serious discussion of how math.se deals with the HNQ, that's not a good way to go about it.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I don't want to open a serious discussion really as I'm not good at debating. I just had an idea that I had mentioned in my question. Apart from that I want to know the reason why mentioned post was removed from HNQ list. Kindly see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list) and [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35045/mod-removing-questions-out-of-hnq) for serious discussions (to no avail). I'm far from placing those kinds of arguments.

Comment: @InanimateBeing - If you only wanted to know the reasons for that one post of yours being removed, you probably shouldn't have said "I feel, ... that the posts should be allowed to automatically show up on the list as they would." Or "Which is very unhealthy for a community (and the individual). I think this must be changed". Or  "... it's best to reconsider the way things are going".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I guess you're right, it's better suited elsewhere, not here atleast. Edited the question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak's mentioned tag `specific-question` is correctly used here. This is post is not a duplicate and should be reopened: OP is asking about their **specific** question. JonathanZ's "All of these recent HNQ-complaining meta posts are based on 'why was mine removed?'" is false: one obvious example mentioned by OP, [Mod removing questions out of HNQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35045/) is a discussion about moderator's behavior, which is NOT AT ALL simply a complain. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) And there are many other different aspects of other mentioned HNQ posts. The unilateral moderator closing of this meta post is unjustified.

Comment: Not clear to me why anyone cares whether or not one of their posts is on the HNQ list.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: one apparent reason for me is that a post on the HNQ list gets more exposure to the public and attracts more attention and hence more chance to get interesting answers. Taking it out of the HNQ deprives such opportunities. And only mods have such power to take it out. One may reasonably concern if moderators are abusing their power.

Comment: @user, does it get exposure to people who are likely to have anything useful to contribute?

Comment: @Ger: You tell me.

Comment: @InanimateBeing - Sorry, are you asking Asaf a question, or are asking why Asaf cares whether one of his posts is on HNQ, or asking why Asaf cares whether any post is on HNQ?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC did you vote to re-open post? While the mod is seemingly very active in removing HNQ posts I wonder why take so much time to check meta? Also, it's strange that despite tagging mods neither the post is considered to open and neither they feel the need to respond though the closure was way too fast.

Comment: "One may reasonably concern if moderators are abusing their power". I disagree. We can discuss how we want the site to use and interact with the HNQ, and how best to acheive that, but throwing accusations of abuse is the kind of paranoid, hostile talk that interferes with us actually having that discussion.

Comment: @Jon your accusation of "accusations of abuse is the kind of paranoid, hostile talk" is paranoid and hostile and I disagree with you. I do not see at all why moderators' decisions cannot be questionable.

Comment: @InanimateBeing - No, I did not vote to re-open the post. I think the closure as a dupe was valid, and you haven't even clarified what your last, obscure comment was intended to mean.

Comment: Questioning moderators decisions and accusing moderators of abusing their powers are very very very different things. Do you not see the difference?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC "reasonably concern" won't translate to "accusations" but genuine concerns. Despite so many meta posts and several users showing their discontent towards certain moderator's actions and the moderator not considering in the least to change their ways in the slightest or themselves propose something so mitigate their concerns is I don't know what you call. It may not like abuse of power to you, but what do *you* call it?

Comment: "Abuse of power" is *always* an accusation. And the moderators are not elected to mitigate the concerns of several discontented users. Y'all are coming across as entitled, selfish, and hostile, and I'm done interacting here.

Comment: Wow! Well English is not my first language and now I really don't know the meaning of "accusation". "the moderators are not elected to mitigate the concerns of several discontented users": Kindly [check this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: The discussion has descended into hostility, so let's avoid that. Secondly, even if it is difficult, let us imagine that the poster of this question has nothing to do with the question whose exclusion from the HNQ is being argued about (although it is there, let's do our best to remove that bias). Once that is done, then I think : the reason this is marked as a duplicate is because reasons given for exclusion before, also apply here (hence a previous answer "answers" this question). Reopen votes are likely from users who believe that the "answer" in those posts can be refuted...

Comment: ... which means that isn't an "answer" anymore. Another point is that the remover of the post is a moderator : so "why was this removed form the HNQ" can only be addressed by them. The rest of us can only talk about whether reasons in the "duplicate" apply or not : and apparently , some don't think so. I request everyone to return to the topic of conversation while avoiding further barbs. While we're at it , I would also like users to make strong cases for and against inclusion of questions in the HNQ. The community needs to talk to the moderators about how HNQs should be handled.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer the posts was marked duplicate before the addition of my explanations for each of the links. Having justified for each of the links, I think the post should at least be opened.  By the mods (&/or community?) so that then I may get a response whether in affirmation or not.

Comment: @InanimateBeing If enough users feel that you deserve a better response, they will vote to reopen the question. The basic worry, as I see expressed by the closer, is that everyone needing to ask about a particular HNQ exclusion will then write a meta post, and we will end up with a glut of questions, the answers to which will always be the same reasons as in the "duplicate" posts, refuted for various reasons by various users. I know we have a "reopen" thread although closure reasons are also very similar : but I have yet to see a multitude of "HNQ exclusions" to merit a thread on its own.

Comment: For example, here is a question : if at all this gets an answer from a mod, then it is likely to be one of the following (1) Reasons mentioned in the "duplicate" posts, which you disagree with (2) "I made a mistake, I apologise" which is something that can be done in a comment (and I think this was also mentioned in a duplicate thread). What can be in this answer that won't have been in previous answers? Or you perhaps just want to hear from Asaf Karagila, personally? That's my primary concern regarding reopening, though I've voted for the same.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer "everyone needing to ask about a particular HNQ exclusion will then write a meta post" this won't be the case if we are told why such posts are removed in the first place. Apart from the reasons mentioned in the question, rest of the outline is very vague. I think until that happens, even if individual user do posts such posts and it's not duplicate then they should be entertained.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I think only AsafKaragila can answer the reason for removal. Other mods aren't really a part in this. So, they may just take/have a guess about it. Though thanks a lot for calming the water.

Comment: @InanimateBeing About the last comment, I agree. About the first, I think it's a question of trust, really. Personally, over [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3067) the OP tried to get the community's feel for the HNQ exclusion actions and collect it in one post for the mod to look at. Given that non-mods have only so much control over what remains in the HNQ, we have to place some trust in the mod. I don't mind keeping this mod honest as this question is trying perhaps to do. Note that your association with the post is also, unfortunately, swaying the conversation here

Comment: *Personally* : in previous answers relating to the HNQ , I have seen the moderator in question saying "maybe I acted too rashly", "sometimes honest mistakes happen". While I'm not saying that there isn't a pattern, perhaps letting the mod off the hook, because this could in fact be a mistake, is a possibility here. If I have to be truly , truly honest : the only reason I believe this post could have been removed from the HNQ is because of it has too much of a "my question is in the title" feeling to it : but otherwise, not much wrong in it, in fact, much is right with it.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer in your 2nd comment, the first 2 quotations aren't (valid) reasons. If mod realizes such things happen then they shouldn't do as much or take some other measures to not let that happen (involving some other mod? or *something* else (discussing with community)). And also consider restoring the HNQ status. Your last sentence I don't get. I'm here as it happened to me and I found it unjust.

Comment: (1) Not that you requested my opinion, but: I believe that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30672/) addresses why, I, personally, would have removed the question from the HNQ.  Read past the bit about titles.  The relevant quotes are "When this feature was introduced, there was a fairly unanimous agreement between the moderators that questions on the HNQ should reflect content as we want it, rather as picked by an algorithm," and "If they are lacking context, or somehow very uninteresting ("please verify my proof that sine integrates to cosine"), they should be removed."

Comment: (2) In this case, my feeling is that the question you asked is *not* the best that Math SE has to offer.  It is a problem statement together with an image that has moderate explanatory power, and some musings on the problem which contain no actual mathematical content.  The presence of images is somewhat click-baity (I have often joked that the best way to get a highly-upvoted answer is to include an image), and the self-answer artificially inflates the "hotness" of the question.  This question, whether intentionally or not, could not have been better designed to appeal to the algorithm.

Comment: (3) Note:  this does not mean that I think that the question is *bad*---I do not think that it should be closed or deleted.  However, I also do not think that it is the *best* that Math SE has to offer, hence the space is occupied on the HNQ is better spent on another question.  [See also](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30753/).

Comment: @InanimateBeing They aren't valid reasons : just quotes from previous answers. I agree that I'm asking for charity, however. I woke up about an hour ago, and saw the vote skew on our comments thread : it seems that people do not wish to be as charitable as me. I cannot fault that because previous threads saw a divide, and I don't see anything wrong in the removed question apart from the "stretched" interpretation of "question similar to title" I used earlier. The reason I'm asking for charity is purely based on the fact that I trust this mod : yet I'm voting to reopen because...

Comment: ... , in the hope that there isn't a descent into hostility, there can be more conversation about this and that the community can send a stronger message than last time (in $2019$) that such removals are unacceptable and much more care must be taken in HNQ exclusion than is currently the case. If such messages are not sent strongly (and some messages above clearly indicate that feelings are not very strong) then I can't see action. *If* the message is clear, then IMO we should start working on compromises. That's a better use of time. That requires both parties to chime in.

Comment: One last thing : I'm not pointing fingers or blaming you for asking about your own question, @Inanimate. I had two reasons for making that comment. I'm trying to keep the HNQ exclusion of this particular question at the center by making everybody's role with respect to it uniform, otherwise the fact that you are in fact the question asker will become a tangent discussion. Perhaps this could be my *fear* : if so, I apologize for projecting it here. However, I've seen many threads descend to name-calling and bad-faith attribution, and want to avert such a possibility here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you for your considerate comments. Though there are some issues. (1) "reflect content as we want it" & "somehow very uninteresting" essentially translates to the former and can, as a blanket, justify **anything** and so I think it's the root cause of the problem and many members are not liking it this way. Please, if you mods care, heed to our concerns, they are not for naught. If I were a single case then perhaps ignoring would be fine but the issue is raised several times so I think we need a stricter format than that & also not just 1 mod going rampant over the list.

Comment: ... (2) I respect your opinions about the question but the community felt otherwise and so I went on the HNQ list. "could not have been better designed to appeal to the algorithm": Well, this is **very** unhealthy, considering you assume everyone guilty and look at it that way. If someone scores high, I may assume they cheated or that they worked hard. I not know except if I assume the latter, then I'll accept the score and if I assume the former, instead of rejecting the score, I must check their background or check their behavior in past (& future?). Then come to conclusion. ...

Comment: I think it would be great that like the case with most things, instead of just silently removing the post from HNQ, the user should be warned if you think they are being out of what is considered right. Otherwise HNQ shouldn't be interfered with at least as much but a lot less. (3) "better spent on another question" this mostly answered by (1) but also, the "recent question" mentioned in my question is also not in my view (trying my best to raising it to your (collective) standards) very undeserving but it was on the list for 2 days. And I think this is expected to happen. Because...

Comment: While having an idea of "the best" you don't (imo) first curate the list of all the possible candidates and then select the winner. But more like: not this, not this, not this... not this either... today's not a good day, let make do with this one. (Just a hunch).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer thank you for being always wonderful. I think everyone is ready to chime in and talk about compromises/mutual understanding. I think in that case, we should all talk about the *ways* to *deal* with the problem instead of just asking for reasons and seeing such actions continue to eternity to many users' discontentment. [contd]

Comment: If I may suggest, it would be best if mods themselves create a meta post asking for views and suggestions on possible ways to mitigate the problem. There all sorts of suggestions will come as answers and the most popular suggestion will get highly upvoted. We understand the necessity of moderators' intervention just like with everything else but this issue in particular is (totally) different. Later discussions, if required, may be done further on that answer or may be the top 3 "nominees", however the community wishes.

Comment: @InanimateBeing "I respect your opinions about the question but the community felt otherwise and so I went on the HNQ list. " The fact that you can say that seems to indicate that you have not read (or perhaps understood) Asaf's statements about the algorithm which puts things *on* the HNQ.  (Hint:  "the community" has little to do with it).

Comment: In any event, as far as I can tell, the question you asked here has been answered, and discussed to death, both here and in previous posts.  It is clear that you don't like the answer, and disagree with it.  Such is life.  I am not going to debate this with you any further.